# Coins object isn't following functions set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an NSMutableArray (named coins) that isn't following a randomPoint method. When I go to iOS Simulator, the coins don't show up (as in there are no images) and they stay in the center of the screen instead of a randomly assigned point. This is what should make a new coin:

```
if ([coins count] == 0){

    CGSize windowSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    CGPoint randomPointOnScreen = ccp((float)(arc4random() % 100) / 100 * windowSize.width, (float)(arc4random() % 100) / 100 * windowSize.height);

   randomCoinType = arc4random() % kNumberOfCoinTypes + 1; // I have this because my files are named like "coin.1.png" and such
```

kNumberOfCoinTypes is defined as 10 to give me a number 1-10.
This is the corresponding void that should make the coins:

```
-(void)createCoinsAt:(CGPoint)position withCointype:(int)type{

NSString *imageFile;

switch (type) {


    case 1:

        imageFile = @"coin.1.png";
        break;

    case 2:
        imageFile = @"coin.2.png";
        break;

    case 9:
    case 3:
        imageFile = @"coin.3.png";
        break;

    case 7:
    case 8:
    default:
    case 4:
        imageFile = @"coin.4.png";
        break;

    case 5:
        imageFile = @"coin.5.png";
        break;

    case 6:
        imageFile = @"coin.6.png";
        break;

      }

Coins *c = [Coins spriteWithFile:imageFile];
//Coins *c = [Coins spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"coin.%d.png", arc4random() % 5 + 1 ]];

c.type = type;
c.position = position;
c.velocity = ccp(0,0);
[coins addObject:c];
[self addChild:c z:2];
```

}

I have multiple cases following one command because I don't know how to make one number appear more often than another.

Comment: What do you mean it's not "following" functions? What is the actual problem you're having? It is unclear from what you've posted.

Comment: What lolcat said. If you're going to use terminology, please either use standard terminology or describe the concept in plain English. "Following functions," "setting it to follow," "corresponding void," "following one command" — I can guess at what these mean, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The random function and basic calculation look fine.  What's in `ccp()`?

Comment: @gaige `ccp()` is just a cocos2d macro used to shorten up `CGPointMake()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine with the code you've shown. Your problems are probably in your `Coin` class.

Things to check in your `Coin` class:

- Does setting `velocity` to {0,0} inadvertently change `position`?
- What `CCSprite` methods have you overridden? Make sure to call the `super` of those methods.

Other things to try:

- Can you make a `coin.1.png` visibly appear at a random point using only the `CCSprite` class?  If not...

  - Make sure the physical `coin.1.png` file is correctly added to your project.
  - Check the parent objects: are they flagged as invisible? are they added to the scene?

---

UPDATE: Avoiding subclassing CCSprite

```
@interface Coin : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *sprite;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint velocity; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) int type;
@end
```

--

```
-(void)createCoinAt:(CGPoint)position withCointype:(int)type{

    NSString *imageFile;
    ...
    //imageFile switch statement here
    ...
    Coin *c = [[Coin alloc] init];

    c.sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:imageFile];
    c.sprite.position = position;
    c.type = type;
    c.velocity = ccp(0,0);
    [coins addObject:c];
    [parentNode addChild:c.sprite z:2]; //make sure to add to correct parent CCNode
}
```

--
Once a Coin is given a velocity:

```
//duration assumes velocity is pixels-per-second
CCAction *moveSprite = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:c.velocity]];
[c.sprite runAction:moveSprite];
```

Once a Coin disappears/dies/whatever:

```
[c.sprite stopAllActions];
[c.sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
c.sprite = nil;
[coins removeObject:c];
```

Comment: `velocity = CGPointZero;` I have that to stop it. I don't know if it would keep the velocity setting to (0,0) from changing the position. I believe it stops it.   `[self setPosition:ccp(self.position.x + velocity.x, self.position.y + velocity.y)];` I also have that but I don't think that's doing anything.

Comment: I can make a coin appear using the CCSprite class though.

Comment: @PaulTerrell-Perica Then your `Coin` class is probably messing things up somehow.  Maybe try replicating your functionality without subclassing `CCSprite`?

Comment: Easier said than done. Any recommendations for how and where to start?

Comment: @PaulTerrell-Perica Updated answer with a few things... maybe it'll help, maybe not?

Comment: that may not work fully because I'm using things like scheduleUpdate and setDisplayFrame: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName, etc...

Comment: @PaulTerrell-Perica Yeah, I think we've taken this topic to the point where I can't give you good advice without having your entire code-base.  To be clear, I dont feel that avoiding subclassing `CCSprite` is necessary, I was just trying to think of a way to help you discover your problem by breaking into separate chunks.  Beyond that, all I can say is "set lots of breakpoints and step through code!" Anyway, best of luck to you. =)